# Testing drag and drop with behat and mink

Tags: behat, mink

I'm trying to emulate drag and drop UI behaviour in a behat test. So far with no success, despite mink [allegedly supporting that interaction](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/interacting-with-pages.html#drag-n-drop).

Weirdly enough it was hard for me to find any relevant blog posts about the subjects. Ones I've found ([this](https://medium.com/@smartgamma/how-to-test-drag-and-drop-elements-with-behat-selenium-5a56154fecfe#.yaqhwbi5a) and http://www.pix-art.be/post/testing-drag-and-drop-with-behat-and-guzzle
) did not help me much. Especially the latter one.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach the problem or has experience with actually testing that interaction?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://medium.com/@smartgamma/how-to-test-drag-and-drop-elements-with-behat-selenium-5a56154fecfe#.55iyeur4q

Comment: Yes, it's also linked in my question.

Comment: Do you have a link to some public demo/website with this type of functionality?

Comment: ](No, unfortunately I cannot disclose the code. It's basically a UI for dragging stuff between columns. Built using [dragular](https://github.com/luckylooke/dragular) and angular 1.6.*

Answer (score 0):

you can find an working example in the ownCloud test code, it does move files into folders via drag-and-drop:

```
    public function moveFileTo(
        $name, $destination, Session $session, $maxRetries = STANDARD_RETRY_COUNT
    ) {
        $toMoveFileRow = $this->findFileRowByName($name, $session);
        $destinationFileRow = $this->findFileRowByName($destination, $session);
        $this->initAjaxCounters($session);
        $this->resetSumStartedAjaxRequests($session);
        for ($retryCounter = 0; $retryCounter < $maxRetries; $retryCounter++) {
            $toMoveFileRow->findFileLink()->dragTo(
                $destinationFileRow->findFileLink()
            );
            $this->waitForAjaxCallsToStartAndFinish($session);
            $countXHRRequests = $this->getSumStartedAjaxRequests($session);
            if ($countXHRRequests === 0) {
                \error_log("Error while moving file");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($retryCounter > 0) {
            $message
                = "INFORMATION: retried to move file $retryCounter times";
            echo $message;
            \error_log($message);
        }
    }
```

from: https://github.com/owncloud/core/blob/47396de109965110276deb545a9bd09f375c9823/tests/acceptance/features/lib/FilesPageCRUD.php#L243

First it finds the `NodeElement` of the file that has to be moved, then then `NodeElement` of the destination and calls `$fileToBeMovedElement->dragTo($destinationElement)`

Because it proved to be flaky there is an retry loop around the `dragTo` function. To test if the drag-and-drop operation worked the code checks if any AJAX calls were set off or not (in this particular app this drag-and-drop operation sets off an WebDAV request)